# not able to install php7.0 in ubuntu18.04 LTS

Tags: php

I’m not able to install PHP 7.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. It is showing only PHP 7.1 and PHP 7.2.

Has anybody tried installing on 18.04?

Comment: What is showing only php7.1 & php7.2.? Which command did you run?

Comment: Firstly, why do you not want an up to date PHP?

Comment: No actually my application does not support php7.2

Comment: I would recommend having a look into using Docker, makes managing versions etc. worth the initial learning curve of a new tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP 7.2 is the version Ubuntu 18.04 ships.

```
apt-cache policy php

php:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:7.2+60ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:7.2+60ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

If you want another PHP version you need to add an addition repository (for example a PPA).
For Ubuntu I recommend this one: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

Then you need to version select the package when interacting with APT.

```
apt-cache policy php7.0

php7.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.30-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.0.30-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 sudo su
 //enter password
 apt-get install python-software-properties

 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

 apt-get update

 apt-get install -y php7.0
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.